# How does the 'max' as a variable work even though normally it is a function?

Tags: c++, function, variables, max

i'm like 6 months in C++, only practicing algorithm problems, but I know no more than that.

how does this work? declaring `max` as a variable even though normally it is a function?
shouldn't the computer confuse them?
(or at least I think it's a function since it appears with green on C++)
what I mean is how does the computer know when i'm using `max` as a variable and when i'm using it as a function?

Thanks!

Comment: The compiler *doesn't* know. If you have a variable, and a function with the same name, the compiler will object.

Comment: `max` function is in `std::`, so shouldn't interfere with `max` variable, unless you do something like `using namespace std;` which is generally a bad idea anyway.

Comment: And unless you `#include <algorithm>`, the `std::max` function will not be declared.

Comment: yes, i'm `using namespace std` . from what i've heard it's not a big deal to not use it, but this case actually explains the importance of not using it.

Comment: @heapunderrun Unless any other header includes that (which would be perfectly fine thing to do).

Answer (score 0):

Scope.

`max`-the-variable will replace `max`-the-function or `max`-the-type if declared in a narrower scope. Compilation will fail if you declare `max`-the function and `max` the variable in the same scope or introduce ambiguity.

Let's look at a few examples:

```cpp
int max(int x, int y);
int max;
int main()
{
    max = max(10,4);
}
```

This fails to compile outright because we have two different declarations of `max` at the same scope.

```
namespace test
{
    int max(int x, int y);
}
using namespace test;
int max;
int main()
{
    max = max(10, 4);
}
```

This also fails to compile because the using statement makes which `max` you want ambiguous even though both `max`s are in different scopes. This case can be fixed by removing the ambiguity: `::max = test::max(10, 4);`.

```cpp
int max(int x, int y);
int main()
{
    int max = max(10, 4);
}
```

This one fails because `int max` is in a narrower scope and replaces `int max(int x, int y)`. There is no ambiguity; the code is trying to call an `int` as a function, and the function `max` is no longer visible.

```cpp
int max(int x, int y);
int main()
{
    int max = 42;
}
```

is totally valid. `max` is unambiguously an `int` and `max` isn't used as a function.

Note: `int max = max;` will compile, but max will be initialized with its uninitialized self. Not very useful, but I'm sure there's some weird trick that can take advantage of this behaviour.

There is a bit more leeway with `max` the type.

```cpp
struct max
{

};
max max;
```

is valid, but

```cpp
struct max
{

};
max max;
max fail;
```

is not. After `max max`, `max` is a variable and `max`-the-type is lost. Take away from this is avoid the always-popular `string string;` and `map map`.